# Changing name of image uploaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm a noob django developer, I can upload images but name of the images have to be changed to image ID or whatever I want.

In addition to this, when I delete entries, images are still resting in the media file but I don't want this.

What I have to add ?

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Flower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/media')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the path and filename of where the files are stored, you'll need to define a method for upload_to. Here's an example:

```
def my_upload_to(instance, filename):
    # "instance" is an instance of Flower
    # return a path here
    return 'my/path/to/storage/' + filename

class Flower(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=my_upload_to)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield

To delete the underlying file, you'll need to make a call manually:

```
flower = Flower.objects.get(id=1)
flower.image.delete()
```

You can choose to override your model's `delete()` method, or use signals `pre_delete` or `post_delete` to delete the associated files automatically.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile

Comment: I modified my_upload_to like "def my_upload_to(self, instance, filename): " and not worked; TypeError at /admin/site1/flower/add/
my_upload_to() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: you can't add the `self` parameter to your upload_to method, the signature must be exactly `def something(instance, filename)`

Comment: Eclipse gives an error then. "Method my_upload_to should have self as  first parameter "

Comment: Ok I did what you said, it adds "media" to image name. Not changing whole name.

    def my_upload_to(instance, filename):

        return 'static/media' + filename
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=my_upload_to)

Comment: You don't need to use `filename` in your method, the answer I provided was just an example. Here's another one: `def my_upload_to(instance, filename): return instance.name+'.jpg'`. You should write `my_upload_to` method to return the name you want to store the file as.

Comment: I have another question, how can I resize image ?

Comment: @GaripTipici You should ask another question on StackOverflow- other people and I would answer your question there.